# Next value for Sequence Function

Tags: sql-server, functions, sequence

Why does this give me the same value, four 1?

```
USE [TSQL2012]
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sqlsequence', 'SO') IS NOT NULL
    DROP SEQUENCE dbo.sqlsequence;
GO
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS INT 
START WITH 1
MAXVALUE 8 CYCLE

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR
        [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS [Seq1] ,
    NEXT VALUE FOR
        [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS [Seq2] ,
    NEXT VALUE FOR
        [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS [Seq3] ,
    NEXT VALUE FOR
        [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS [Seq4]
```

But this works fine as expected.  Gives me 1, 2, 3, 4

```
USE [TSQL2012]
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sqlsequence', 'SO') IS NOT NULL
    DROP SEQUENCE dbo.sqlsequence;
GO
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS INT 
START WITH 1
MAXVALUE 8 CYCLE

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR
        [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS [Seq1]
SELECT          NEXT VALUE FOR
        [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS [Seq2]
SELECT          NEXT VALUE FOR
        [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS [Seq3]
SELECT           NEXT VALUE FOR
        [dbo].[SQLSequence] AS [Seq4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx) states:

> The NEXT VALUE FOR function is nondeterministic, and is only allowed in contexts where the number of generated sequence values is well defined. Below is the definition of how many values will be used for each referenced sequence object in a given statement:
>
> `SELECT` - For each referenced sequence object, **a new value is generated once per row in the result of the statement**.

Comment: @MartinSmith: many lols

Comment: 4 seconds faster!